# wp7 facebook integration - sorry, something went wrong

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

I get this error message when I try to authorize using my wp7 app with facebook.  Instead of showing the authorization page with the list of permissions that my application is attempting to get, the browser displays this message

"sorry, something went wrong"

The call to go get the access_token is never made because of this.

Pratik

Comment: what are you doing/attempting when you get this response?

Comment: From my app page, I redeirect the browser control to navigate to facebook's authorize URL (display=touch).  Once I put in the user credentials on facebook page and hit Login, instead of bringing up the page which specifies what permissions my app is trying to get, the page just shows that error. When I change the display to wap, everything works correctly.  Facebook recommends using display = touch for mobile but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the sample in the source of the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/); I am the author of the sample. You don't necessarily have to use our SDK, but to get where you want to go doesn't require our SDK, so the sample should be fairly self-explanatory. Our docs also include some info on our sample.

Comment: DevTheo, thanks for this link.  This looks promising.  I will read through this and try it out.

Comment: DevTheo, please see my follow up question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360329/wp7-logout-facebook  Any guidance you can provide regarding how to logout on WP7 will be helpful.