# wp7 logout facebook

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I plan to use http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/ for replacing my current integration with facebook.  Any sample that demonstrates the logout process from facebook on WP7 using this library?

I am able to login using OAuth right now but don't know how to logout. Just clearing the AccessToken doesn't work (this approach works for Twitter)

Pratik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else looking to do this - checkout the answer (#2 at this time) from Sumit at this link [Facebook Oauth Logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764436/facebook-oauth-logout)

This is not using the facebook SDK I mentioned earlier but it works.  As I integrate my app further, would look more into the library.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the InvokeScript method on the WebBrowser control to click the logout button on the Facebook webpage.

http://dotnetcatch.wordpress.com/2011/08/26/wp7-facebook-logout-issues/

Answer (score 0):

I just recently ran across this issue.  I found a way that works very easily... I just created a hidden WebBrowser control, then navigated to this link:

https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}&confirm=1&next={YOUR_URL_ENCODED_WEBSITE_TO_RETURN_TO}

Seems rather simple, and after trying a slew of other methods I can't believe it actually worked, but it does work for me on Mango!  Thought I'd share in case anyone else is still struggling!